# Can't convert string to hex int to use in chr()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write a code to print chemical equations in a readable form. I've got all other parts working aside from the subscripts. I know the subscripts will range from 1 to 9, and the hex code is 0x2081 - 0x2089 accordingly.

If the user inputs O_2, it will attach the needed 2 to the hexadecimal to create 0x2082, giving me the subscript 2. However, I can't convert the string '0x2082' into a usable type for chr.

```
uni = '0x208'
el = input("Enter element (with optional underscore): ")
if ('_' in el):
  end = str(el[len(el)-1])
  hex_code = uni + end
  print(hex_code)
  sub = chr(int(hex_code))
```

Anything to point me in the right direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
In [1]: chr(0x2082)
Out[1]: '₂'
```

So all you need to do is something like this:

```
text = 'O_2' # take from user input
subzero = 0x2080
subchr = chr(subzero + int(text[-1]))
```